# Android USB Accessory connection with Arduino and USB Host shield

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I have the following components.

**Device:**

1. Arduino Uno R3 (Original)
2. USB Host Shield (from [sparkfun.com](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9947))
3. ASUS Zenfone 2 (Android 5.0 Version)

**Software:**

1. Arduino IDE (1.6.5)
2. USB Host Shield (Library 2.0)
3. Android Studio (1.3.2)

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to connect with my Android phone with my Arduino for simple data communication.

**My problems:**

I don't understand what's wrong! My ADK (from library) can't recognize my Android phone with the Arduino USB shield. I have been wasting a couple of weeks :( .
Please help me.

**Here is my code:**

**Arduino Sketch:**

```
#include <adk.h>
// Satisfy IDE, which only needs to see the include statement in the Uno.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#endif

USB Usb;
ADK adk(&Usb, "DemoTestKit", // Manufacturer Name
  "DemoKit", // Model Name
  "Example sketch for the USB Host Shield",
  "1.0", // Version
  "http://www.example.com", // URL (web page to visit if no installed apps support the accessory)
  "123456789"); // Serial Number (optional)
uint32_t timer;
bool connected;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  #if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
    while (!Serial);
    // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
  #endif
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print("\r\nOSCOKIRQ failed to assert");
    while (1); // halt
  }
  Serial.print("\r\nArduino Started");
}

void loop() {
  Usb.Task();
  if (adk.isReady()) {
    Serial.print("\r\nADK Ready");
    if (!connected) {
      connected = true;
      Serial.print(F("\r\nConnected to accessory"));
    }
  } else {
    if (connected) {
      connected = false;
      Serial.print(F("\r\nDisconnected from accessory"));
    }
  }
}
```

Here `adk.isReady()` is not working.

**Android Code:-----------**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.softpider.usb.usbtest" >
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**accessory_filter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <usb-accessory model="DemoKit" manufacturer="DemoTestKit" version="1.0"/>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public static final boolean D = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  // This is automatically set when building
  private static final String TAG = "ArduinoBlinkLEDActivity";
  // TAG is used to debug in Android logcat console
  private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.softpider.usb.usbtest";
  UsbAccessory mAccessory;
  ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor;
  FileInputStream mInputStream;
  FileOutputStream mOutputStream;
  private UsbManager mUsbManager;
  private PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
  private boolean mPermissionRequestPending;
  TextView connectionStatus;
  private TextView textView;
  UsbAccessory accessory;
  private UsbDevice device;

  private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
        synchronized (this) {
          accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
          if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
            if(accessory != null) {
              openAccessory(accessory);
            }
          } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for accessory " + accessory);
          }
          mPermissionRequestPending = false;
        }
      }
      if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
        accessory = (UsbAccessory)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
        if (accessory != null) {
          closeAccessory();
        }
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("OnCreate");
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
  }
  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // textView.setText("OnResume");
    if (mAccessory != null) {
      setConnectionStatus(true);
      return;
    }
    // Log.i(TAG, "Device List: " + deviceList);
    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    UsbAccessory[] accessories = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
    // textView.setText(Arrays.toString(accessories));
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
    device = deviceList.get("<deviceName>");
    Log.i(TAG, "Accessories List: " + accessories);
    if (accessories != null) {
      if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(accessory)) {
        openAccessory(accessory);
        textView.setText("OnResume IF False");
      } else {
        setConnectionStatus(false);
        textView.setText("OnResume IF Else False");
        synchronized (mUsbReceiver) {
          if (!mPermissionRequestPending) {
            mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
            mPermissionRequestPending = true;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      setConnectionStatus(false);
      // textView.setText("OnResume Else False");
      if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "mAccessory is null");
    }
  }
  private void openAccessory(UsbAccessory accessory) {
    textView.setText("Accessory Open");
  }
  private void setConnectionStatus(boolean connected) {
    connectionStatus.setText(connected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected");
  }
  private void closeAccessory() {
    setConnectionStatus(false);
    textView.setText("Accessory Close");
  }
}
```

I can't understand what will be the `ACTION_USB_PERMISSION` string?

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.softpider.usb.usbtest";
```

or

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.softpider.usb.usbtest.USB_PERMISSION";
```

or

```
private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.softpider.usb.USB_PERMISSION";
```

Comment: when you gives supply to arduino is any dialogue box open to ask AndroidAccessary connected and checkbox to check??

Comment: No.. No dialouge box open @Amol Sawant 96 Kuli

Comment: first check your device supports to Android accessory?. change device and check it again. if it not giving any dialogue then may be your  USB Host Shield having problem.

Comment: But my usb host shield can connect a flash drive (fat format) @Amol Sawant 96 Kuli

Comment: And by the way can you tell me what will be my ACTION_USB_PERMISSION string? plz see my question bellow

Comment: see @zxprince, if there is no android apk in android phone to communicate with Arduino then also it will give pop-up dialogue of Android accessory connected and says that no apk for DemoKit.

Comment: Go through the Arduino uno R3 datashit or help document. Arduino having one LED  'L' which tells you Android device connected or not.

Comment: So what should i do now? Plz suggest me?

Comment: did you checked connecting arduino with other Android device??

Comment: Yes.. 4 more android phone... same matter.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, but I'm doing something similar at the moment. 
So, I believe your problem was that you didn't call `init()` method to initialize ADK.

```
#include <adk.h>

...

int main(void) {
    init();
    setup();
    for (;;) {
        loop();
    }
}
```